# Shell programming --Extract values of 2 key words

Tags: shell, sed, key, extract

Input file (HTTP request log file):

GET /dynamic_branding_playlist.fmil?**domain=915oGLbNZhb**&pluginVersion=3.2.7_2.6&pubchannel=usa&**sdk_ver=2.4.6.3**&width=680&height=290&embeddedIn=http%3A%2F%2Fviewster.com%2Fsplash%2FOscar-Videos-1.aspx%3Futm_source%3Dadon_272024_113535_24905_24905%26utm_medium%3Dcpc%26utm_campaign%3DUSYME%26adv %3D573900%26req%3D5006e9ce1ca8b26347b88a7.1.825&sdk_url=http%3A%2F%2Fdivaag.vo.llnwd.net%2Fo42%2Fhtt p_only%2Fviewster_com%2Fv25%2Fyume%2F&viewport=42

Out put file:

domain   sdk_version

915oGLbNZhb 2.4.6.3

Thousands of logs similar to the example above, so I need to find a way to extract the value of domain&sdk_version. And the positions of domain and sdk_version are not fixed. sometimes appear in the 2 field, sometimes apprear in the last field (if split by &).

Could anyone help me in this problem (using sed command)? Thanks so much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/.*\<\(domain\)=\([^&]*\).*\<\(sdk_ver\)=\([^&]*\).*/\1 \3sion\n\2 \4/p;d' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
sed -n 's/.*domain=\([^&]*\).*sdk_ver=\([^&]*\).*/\1 \2/p' input_file
```

Comment: But some output like this:879QceaskgD sl_0_1_2 HTTP/1.1", 200, 64, 1228, 11263, "http://lightningstream.surfernetwork.com/Media/player/ClientBin/YuMePlayer.xap", plg5.yumenetworks.com, "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)", "67_240_57_227_mfTZ4YG36ztVVB", "0rO0ABXcoAAAAAwAAATsAAAVAAAAGdgAAAVoAAAZtAAAGdgAAAVkAAAZlAAAGdg**", "-", "-", "@YD_1;2707_0", -, "-"

Comment: The format of sdk_version is not N.N.N.N, it maybe like S_N_N_N or N.N.N,how do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    FS = "[&?]"
    printf "domain\tsdk_version\n"
}

{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        split ($i, array, "=")
        if (array[1] == "domain") {
            printf array[2]
        }
        if (array[1] == "sdk_ver") {
            printf "\t%s", array[2]
        }
    }
    printf "\n"
}
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
awk -F "[&?]" 'BEGIN { printf "domain\tsdk_version\n" } { for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) { split ($i, array, "="); if (array[1] == "domain") printf array[2]; if (array[1] == "sdk_ver") printf "\t%s", array[2]; } printf "\n"; }' file.txt
```

Results:

```
domain  sdk_version
915oGLbNZhb 2.4.6.3
```